# Multi-redirect form using PHP and form values. I am lost

Tags: php, forms

What I am trying to get work is when a user fills out the form if they choose one of the services in the drop-down as well as the home radio button and entering a correct San Diego zip code it takes them to that page in the drop-down.  If they don't enter a correct San Diego zip code it automatically redirects them to the nationwide page.  The issue that I am having is with the radio buttons.  What I need to happen is when the user selects a drop-down from the list and chooses the office radio button it redirects them to the office version to whatever that drop-down was.  They also have to enter a correct SD zip here as well or they get sent to nationwide page.  I really need help just getting this to redirect correctly, I thought I had it with the current code I have but I just only get redirected to the home drop-down selections, even if the office radio button is the one selected. Can someone please please help me out with this I am super lost right now and can't think of why its not working. 
Thanks

FORM:

```
<div class="home-form">
    <form method='get' id='gform_1'  action='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/form-handler/'>
        <div class="serviceinput"
            <label for="services">Services: </label>
            <select id="selection" name="selection">
                <option value='-1'>Select a Service</option>
                <option value="0">Water Delivery</option>
                <option value="1">Coffee Services</option>
                <option value="2">Water Filtration</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        &nbsp;
        <div class="zipcode">
            <label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
            <input name="zip" type="text" maxlength="5" id="zip" />
        </div>
        <div class="frontradio">
            <input name="home" type="radio" id="homeradio" />
            <div class="homelabel"> 
                <label for="homeradio">Home</label>
            </div>
            <input name="home" type="radio" id="officeradio" />
            <label for="officeradio">Office</label>
        </div>
        <div class="homebutton">
            <input type='submit' id="submithome" name="did_submit" value="Get Started!">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

FORM HANDLER:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Form Handler
 */
?>  
 <?php
    if(isset($_GET['zip'])){
        $sandiego = array('91911', '91914', '91915', '91932', '91942', '91945', '91950', '92014', '92025', '92027', '92029', '92037', '92064', '92065', '92067', '92071', '92075', '92101', '92102', '92103', '92104', '92105', '92106', '92107', '92108', '92109', '92110', '92111', '92113', '92114', '92115', '92116', '92117', '92118', '92119', '92120', '92121', '92122', '92123', '92124', '92126', '92127', '92128', '92129', '92130', '92131', '92132', '92134', '92135', '92139', '92140', '92145', '92147', '92154', '92173', '92562', '92563', '92590', '92591', '92592', '92596');
      if (in_array($_GET['zip'], $sandiego)){
          $urls = array();
            if($_GET["home"] == 1) { 
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/";
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/";
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/";
            } else {
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-delivery-service/";
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/coffee-delivery/";
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-filtration-systems/";
            }
            if($_GET['selection'] < 3 && $_GET['selection'] >= 0) {
                $URL = $urls[$_GET['selection']];
                header("Location: $URL?zip=$_GET[zip]");
            } else header("Location: http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/nationwide/"); 
        } else {
            header("Location: http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/nationwide/");
        }
    }
    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your HTML form:

```
<input name="home" type="radio" id="homeradio" />
...
<input name="home" type="radio" id="officeradio" />
```

Your radio buttons don't have a value attribute. Try something like:

```
<input name="home" type="radio" value="homeradio" />
...
<input name="home" type="radio" value="officeradio" />
```

Then in your PHP:

```
if($_GET["home"] == "homeradio") { 
    // home URLs here
    $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/";
    $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/";
    $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/";
} elseif($_GET["home"] == "officeradio") { 
    // office URLs here
    $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-delivery-service/";
    $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/coffee-delivery/";
    $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-filtration-systems/";
} else {
    // any other options can go here
}
```

Comment: Would I need to add my URL variables within each of those parameters... so would this be the correct way of doing this:

Comment: if($_GET["home"] == "homeradio") {                             $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/";
$urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/";
} elseif($_GET["home"] == "officeradio") { 
} else {
}